# How to disable auto-recognition of file types when IntelliJ is started

Tags: intellij-idea

I am working with the file type *.properties, for which I don't want to use IntelliJ's property file editor, which is assigned to that file extension by default. In Settings > Editor > Code Style > FileTypes, I have removed the "*.properties" pattern from the "Properties" under Recognized File Types, and added it to "Text". This works until I restart IntelliJ, then it automatically reassigns "*.properties" to "Properties". In the bottom right corner, it shows a corresponding message with a "Revert"-Button, to undo IntelliJ's auto reassignment:

[image]

Is it possible to disable this auto-reassignment? If yes, how?

Comment: Looks like a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-172658.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent IntelliJ IDEA from reassigning file type associations at startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499457/how-can-i-prevent-intellij-idea-from-reassigning-file-type-associations-at-start)