# How can I prevent IntelliJ IDEA from reassigning file type associations at startup?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, jenkins-pipeline, file-association

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 18.1 and Jenkinsfile support is awful. Thankfully, treating the file as Groovy is a workaround I can live with.

This involves

1. Removing the Jenkinsfile association
2. Adding Jenkinsfile under the Groovy group

The problem is every time IDEA starts up fresh, it will remove Jenkinsfile association and, since (1) the original association has been removed, treat these files as plain text.

`File type recognized: File extension Jenkinsfile was reassigned to Jenkins file Revert`

[image: File type recognized: File extension Jenkinsfile was reassigned to Jenkins file]

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-172658) fixed in IntelliJ IDEA [2018.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/). 2018.2 will be released this week.

Comment: Issue was fixed after updating and disabling some apparently conflicting plugins. Many thanks